# How to render API data into React Frontend using functional components?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have successfully created a backend API using Node+Express+MSSQL and tested out the routes using POSTMAN. Now the challenging part is when I try to render the data to front-end using React Functional components/hooks I get some errors. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to render the tags to React page using API. Also I made sure not to have duplicate ID's in my table cause that might cause some more errors and it is a unique field that can use from 'KEY' prop.

Following is the React Code trying to get the output

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../App.css';

const Ctms = (props) => {

const url = 'http://localhost:8090/api/ctms'
const [normac, setNormac] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
axios.get(url)
.then(response => {
console.log(response.data)
setNormac(response.data)
})

}, [url]);

if(normac) {

    return(
    <div>
    {normac.map((ID,shop_order,item_number,item_desc,machine,supplier,feet_coil,Date_on,load_no,loadpc_signoff,pc_staff_load,unloadpc_signoff,pc_staff_unload,Date_off,ctms_id,complete) => (
    
    <div key ={ID.value}>
    
    <p key ={ID.value}>Shop Order : {shop_order.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Item Number : {item_number.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Item Desc : {item_desc.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Machine : {machine.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Supplier : {supplier.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Feet Coil : {feet_coil.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Date On : {Date_on.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Load Number : {load_no.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Load PC Signoff : {loadpc_signoff.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>PC Staff Load : {pc_staff_load.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Unload PC Signoff : {unloadpc_signoff.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>PC Staff Unload : {pc_staff_unload.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Date Off : {Date_off.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>CTMS ID : {ctms_id.value}</p>
    <p key ={ID.value}>Complete : {complete.value}</p>
    
    </div>
    
    ))}
    </div>
    )}
    
return (
<h1>Check the KepServer tags!!!</h1>
)
}

export default Ctms;
```

Sample DB Fiddle

```
CREATE TABLE ctms (
    ID INT,
    shop_order NCHAR(20),
    item_number NCHAR(20),
    item_desc NCHAR(50),
    machine NCHAR(10),
    supplier NCHAR(20),
    feet_coil NCHAR(10),
    Date_on NCHAR(10),
    load_no NCHAR(15),
    loadpc_signoff NCHAR(10),
    pc_staff_load NCHAR(10),
    unloadpc_signoff NCHAR(10),
    pc_staff_unload NCHAR(15),
    Date_off NCHAR(10),
    ctms_id NCHAR(15),
    complete NCHAR(10)
);
    

INSERT INTO ctms (ID,shop_order,item_number,item_desc,machine,supplier,feet_coil,Date_on,load_no,loadpc_signoff,pc_staff_load,unloadpc_signoff,pc_staff_unload,Date_off,ctms_id,complete) VALUES (1,'SO  123456','0345678945','5/8X022 3T PREM COIL','NOR3','SPOTHER','1000','20220505','LOAD1','INSPECTED','AGLENN','INSPECTED','AGLENN','05/06/2022','ctms379669','y');

INSERT INTO ctms (ID,shop_order,item_number,item_desc,machine,supplier,feet_coil,Date_on,load_no,loadpc_signoff,pc_staff_load,unloadpc_signoff,pc_staff_unload,Date_off,ctms_id,complete) VALUES (1,'SO  456789','0345678945','5/8X022 3T PREM COIL','NOR3','SPOTHER','1000','20220505','LOAD1','INSPECTED','AGLENN','INSPECTED','AGLENN','05/06/2022','ctms379670','y');

INSERT INTO ctms (ID,shop_order,item_number,item_desc,machine,supplier,feet_coil,Date_on,load_no,loadpc_signoff,pc_staff_load,unloadpc_signoff,pc_staff_unload,Date_off,ctms_id,complete) VALUES (1,'SO  987654','0345678945','5/8X022 3T PREM COIL','NOR3','SPOTHER','1000','20220505','LOAD1','INSPECTED','AGLENN','INSPECTED','AGLENN','05/06/2022','ctms379671','y');

INSERT INTO ctms (ID,shop_order,item_number,item_desc,machine,supplier,feet_coil,Date_on,load_no,loadpc_signoff,pc_staff_load,unloadpc_signoff,pc_staff_unload,Date_off,ctms_id,complete) VALUES (1,'SO  654321','0345678945','5/8X022 3T PREM COIL','NOR3','SPOTHER','1000','20220505','LOAD1','INSPECTED','AGLENN','INSPECTED','AGLENN','05/06/2022','ctms379672','y');
```

Errors I'm getting ([Reference for the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNaXs.png))

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
- The above error occurred in the  component

Comment: I think `{normac.map((ID,shop_order,...))` should be `{normac.map({ID,shop_order...})`

Comment: Did you mean like this {normac.map({ID,shop_order,item_number,item_desc,machine,supplier,feet_coil,Date_on,load_no,loadpc_signoff,pc_staff_load,unloadpc_signoff,
    pc_staff_unload,Date_off,ctms_id,complete} => ( ? 

I tried it and it's throwing me an expected token error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` is not quite right, and there are few things in the JSX that need fixing.

Give this a shot.

```
{normac.map(x => (

<div key={ID}>

<p>Shop Order : {x.shop_order}</p>
<p>Item Number : {x.item_number}</p>
<p>Item Desc : {x.item_desc}</p>
<p>Machine : {x.machine}</p>
<p>Supplier : {x.supplier}</p>
<p>Feet Coil : {x.feet_coil}</p>
<p>Date On : {x.Date_on}</p>
<p>Load Number : {x.load_no}</p>
<p>Load PC Signoff : {x.loadpc_signoff}</p>
<p>PC Staff Load : {x.pc_staff_load}</p>
<p>Unload PC Signoff : {x.unloadpc_signoff}</p>
<p>PC Staff Unload : {x.pc_staff_unload}</p>
<p>Date Off : {x.Date_off}</p>
<p>CTMS ID : {x.ctms_id}</p>
<p>Complete : {x.complete}</p>

</div>

))}
```

Now you have `x` (as a reference to the current item in the array iteration) that you can reference within the `map` body.  Here `x` will have properties that correspond to the properties of the objects within  `normac` which, presumably, correspond to the column names in your db.

Note, you also don't need to have a `key` on anything but the top level element in a loop, so you only need it on the `<div>`.

In response to the question in your comment, if you want to only work with a single record then you would either need to 1) filter the data returned from the db/api to a single row/entity, or 2) reference only a single item within `normac` instead of mapping through the array.  Something like

```
{normac.length > 0 && (

<div key={normac[0].ID}>

<p>Shop Order : {normac[0]..shop_order}</p>
<p>Item Number : {normac[0]..item_number}</p>
<p>Item Desc : {normac[0]..item_desc}</p>
<p>Machine : {normac[0]..machine}</p>
<p>Supplier : {normac[0]..supplier}</p>
<p>Feet Coil : {normac[0]..feet_coil}</p>
<p>Date On : {normac[0]..Date_on}</p>
<p>Load Number : {normac[0]..load_no}</p>
<p>Load PC Signoff : {normac[0]..loadpc_signoff}</p>
<p>PC Staff Load : {normac[0]..pc_staff_load}</p>
<p>Unload PC Signoff : {normac[0]..unloadpc_signoff}</p>
<p>PC Staff Unload : {normac[0]..pc_staff_unload}</p>
<p>Date Off : {normac[0]..Date_off}</p>
<p>CTMS ID : {normac[0]..ctms_id}</p>
<p>Complete : {normac[0]..complete}</p>

</div>

))}
```

Here, `normac.length` does a quick truthy check that there is something in the array to reference before actually trying to reference it.  Without it you're likely to run into issues trying to reading a property of `undefined` while your data is loading async from the api in your `useEffect`.  You will need to adjust that truthy check depending on which element in the array you want to reference.

If you want to work with *some* of the array values then you can go back to `normac.map()` but filter the array first:

`normac.filter(x => x.ID > 1).map(x => ({<div>...</div>});`

Comment: You are awesome, that really worked. Thank you much for the explanation as well. If it's okay to ask do you know what I would have to change only to display specific row's details only rather than displaying all at once? Currently using the code you provided it's showing all 4 rows data. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Have a look at my edit regarding your other question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the `normac` is a array of object

When you are using `.map` method you have access to `.map((el, index, array) => ...)`

to get the variables you want (ID,shop_order,item_number...) you need to destructure the first argument of the map callback:

`.map(({ ID,shop_order,item_number... }) => ...)`